# Need BlueJ help: Method Call array

Tags: java, arrays, bluej, method-call

Here is my little sourcecode. It works but i need help at method call. I dont know "how to" enter the values.
I make "new SmallestElement ()" and try to call the method.
the message i get:

[image]

What i have to write in the boxes? Can someone make an example?

```
public class SmallestElement {
   public int getSmallestElement(int[] array, int start, int ende) {
       int mitte = (start + ende) / 2;
       if(start == ende) {
           return array[start];
        } else {
            return Math.min(getSmallestElement(array, start, mitte), getSmallestElement(array, mitte+1, ende));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For array you need to enter it like this : {12, 46, 57}
For the other two just enter 0 and the length of your array minus one (because java starts to count at 0)

He is german, so once more in german:

Für dein array musst du eine liste eingeben, wie folgt: {257, 46, 57, 68, 68, 75}
(Ich bin mir grad nicht ganz sicher,  die , könnten auch ; sein)
Die anderen beiden sind einfache zahlen,  die erste sagt , wo in der liste angefangen werden soll zu suchen - java beginnt mit dem zählen bei Null, also sollte hier 0 rein. Das andere setzt den emdpunkt für die Suche.  Sollte bei meinem Beispiel also auf 5 gesetzt werden um alle zahlen mit einzubeziehen.

Wenn es so mit der manuellen eingabe nicht geht, erstelle eine neue Methode,  die dir den array erstellt und befüllt und dann diese Methode aufruft. Zum Beispiel so:

```
Public void erstelleundfindeminimum () {

int[] test = new int[3];
test[0] = 5;
test[1] = 6;
test[2] = 3;

int minimum = getSmallestElement(test, 0, 2);

}
```

Dies sollte dann minimum auf 3 setzen.

Mfg Marenthyu

Comment: Vielen Dank. Dass mit dem Index (bei 0 anfangen bis n-1) weis ich. Hier ging es im die Schreibweise für das Bild. { } war richtig. Ich habs einfach verplant und fand im Internet nichts was mit BlueJ und method call zusammen hing. Dummer Anfängerfehler. Danke ^^°

Comment: Wäre nett wenn du dann meine Antwort entsprechend markieren könntest

Comment: Ist übrigens auch die Schreibweise Wenn man ein array initialisieren und gleichzeitig füllen möchte : int[] test = {13, 24, 57}